# Angular 4 change provider behavior

Tags: angular, service

I have a Tournament class like:

```
class Tournament{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ...
  state: string;
}
```

I have three components like:

- `hidden-tournament`
- `playing-tournament`
- `finished-tournament`

They all have same template and some shared methods like `changeName()` or `delete()`, but also have differences like `addTeam(team: Team)` just on `hidden-tournament` or `finish()` on `playing-tournament`.

I want to change that to a unique `tournament` with all shared and particular methods, and delegate the behavior to a service, but I don't know how to tell the service to act differently for each state of the tournament.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making three components, you could make one component and name it 'TournamentComponent'.

```
  //TournamentComponent.ts 

  import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {  ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

 @Component({
  selector: 'tournament-component',
  template: `
        <div *ngIf="hiddenTournament"> Hidden Tournament HTML </div>
        <div *ngIf="playingTournament"> Playing Tournament HTML </div>
        <div *ngIf="finishedTournament"> Finished Tournament HTM</div>

         `
  })

  export class TournamentComponent implements OnInit {
  finishedTournament:  boolean = false;
  playingTournament: boolean = false;
  hiddenTournament: boolean = false;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit() {

  this.route.data.subscribe(v => {
  if(v['type'] === 'finished') {
   this.finishedTournament = true; 
   //make others false     

   } else if(v['type'] === 'hidden'){
   this.hiddenTournament = true;
   //make others false

  }
  else {
   this.playingTournament = true;
   //make others false
   }


  }
```

Respectively, you can make these changes in routes.

```
  //Routes.ts
  {path: 'tournament/finish',
         component: TournamentComponent,
         data: {type: 'finished'}
   },

   {path: 'tournament/hidden',
         component: TournamentComponent,
         data: {type: 'hidden'}
   },

   {path: 'tournament/playing',
         component: TournamentComponent,
         data: {type: 'playing'}
   }
```

If you have long html, you could use a separate child component for each of them and emit the events respectively to the parent component TournamentComponent. You can achieve such as a sample given below.

```
       //hidden Tournament Component
        <hidden-tournament (onChangeName)="changeName()" 
           *ngIf="hiddenTournament">        

           </hidden-tournament>

        //Hidden  Tournament Component   
        @Component({
        selector: 'hidden-tournament',
        template: `
                 hidden html content
                 <button (click)="saveName("testName")"></button>
                 `
        })

        export class HiddenTournamentComponent {
          @Ouput() onChangeName: EventEmitter<any>;

          saveName(name){
          this.onChangeName(name);
          }

         }
```